# why is my list empty, however I'm appending data in it?

Tags: python, arrays

I'm trying to run a code that part of it is shown. This part takes text files and converts them into an array as shown. The problem is that the list named (data_list) is empty and doesn't store anything. I tried printing it and found that it's an empty list. Any help fixing this error?

the relevant part of the code:

```
def convert_pc2ply(anno_path, save_path):
    """
    Convert original dataset files to ply file (each line is XYZRGBL).
    We aggregated all the points from each instance in the room.
    :param anno_path: path to annotations. e.g. Area_1/office_2/Annotations/
    :param save_path: path to save original point clouds (each line is XYZRGBL)
    :return: None
    """
    data_list = []

    for f in glob.glob(join(anno_path, '*.txt')):
        class_name = os.path.basename(f).split('_')[0]
        if class_name not in gt_class:  # note: in some room there is 'staris' class..
            class_name = 'clutter'
        pc = pd.read_csv(f, header=None, delim_whitespace=True).values
        labels = np.ones((pc.shape[0], 1)) * gt_class2label[class_name]
        data_list.append(np.concatenate([pc, labels], 1))  # Nx7
       
    print(data_list) #this line is to visualize the problem!
    pc_label = np.concatenate((data_list, 0))
    xyz_min = np.amin(pc_label, axis=0)[0:3]
    pc_label[:, 0:3] -= xyz_min

    xyz = pc_label[:, :3].astype(np.float32)
    colors = pc_label[:, 3:6].astype(np.uint8)
    labels = pc_label[:, 6].astype(np.uint8)
    write_ply(save_path, (xyz, colors, labels), ['x', 'y', 'z', 'red', 'green', 'blue', 'class'])
 """
```

the error I get:

```
andla-net\data\S3DIS\Stanford3dDataset_v1.2_Aligned_Version/Area_1/conferenceRoom_1/Annotations
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "data_prepare_s3dis.py", line 81, in <module>
    convert_pc2ply(annotation_path, join(original_pc_folder, out_file_name))
  File "data_prepare_s3dis.py", line 48, in convert_pc2ply
    pc_label = np.concatenate((data_list, 0))
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions, but the array at index 0 has 1 dimension(s) and the array at index 1 has 0 dimension(s)
```

I guess the dimension error is because the data_list array is empty. I printed it for visualization and it's empty!

Comment: Sounds like your for loop is not executing, probably because the sequence returned by `glob.glob(join(anno_path, '*.txt'))` is empty.

Comment: @jfaccioni so how can I fix that? I checked the path and it's correct!

Comment: I can't test because I don't have access to your machine. But if `glob.glob` is returning an empty sequence, something is wrong with your path even if you think it is correct. Common problems with paths as strings include: mixing lowercase/uppercase letters, messing up whitespace, and mixing back/forward slashes

Comment: you can add a check before the loop, to see if there is actually something in the list, e.g.`assert glob.glob(join(anno_path, '*.txt')), 'there is nothing to loop. Files in the directory: {}'.format(os.listdir(anno_path))`